# If $H$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$, then is it necessary that for $x\in H$, $C_G(x)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

So the title is the question:
If $H$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$, then is it necessary that for $x\in H$, $C_G(x)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ ?

I know the inverse is true, i.e. if the centralizer of an element is a normal subgroup, then the element belongs in an abelian normal subgroup. However, I can't really think of a proof for this proposition and I can't find a counter-example.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not necessarily. Try a normal subgroup $H$ of order $4$ in $S_4$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer! A more subjective question then: These counter-examples, e.g. this specific one, did you find it because of your experience and study of the symmetric groups, or is there some train of thought that you could explain to someone who hasn't had so much experience?

Comment: I guess it was experience that made me think immediately that it was very unlikely that this property would be true. After that I just looked for small examples of non-central abelian normal subgroups in which there are elements with larger centralizers, and I think $S_4$ is the smallest of these.